Access Denied: This application does not have the required permissions to access profile information. Pnp Framework
I'm using pnp framework with App registration client id & secret to authenticate to sharepoint site. I'm able to access list & user based on email. I need to find manager of the user from userprofile properties. So i use PeopleManager here. But i get the error at executequery.
                    using (var context = new PnP.Framework.AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl, clientId, clientSecret))
                    {
                        // Retrieve user details
                        var user = context.Web.EnsureUser("useremail@domain.com");
                        PeopleManager peopleManager = new PeopleManager(context);
                        PersonProperties personProperties = peopleManager.GetMyProperties();                    
                        context.Load(personProperties);
 
                        context.ExecuteQuery();
                    }

I have given below permissions to the client id from Azure App registration, what am i missing ?


Access denied is the expected result if you are using a registered Entra ID application with a client secret. Due to security reinforcement, only certificate will work.

FAQ: Can I use other means besides certificates for realizing app-only access for my Azure AD app?
No, all other options are blocked by SharePoint Online and will result
in an Access Denied message.

Source: Granting access via Azure AD App-Only
Try to generate a new certificate for your application with application permissions Sites.FullControl.All and use it to connect to SharePoint.

